# Select multiple rows in UITableview not working when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I'm ising this code.when i scroll the tableview previous selected items are deselected automatically

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep index of every selected row such as in an array. Then under cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can set the accessoryType regarding those selected row indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` reuse the rows when scrolling. So you have to track the selected rows by yourself. Set/Unset the selection on the render method of the `UITableViewController`.